# Trying to avoid form from resubmitting with PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I am trying to avoid re-submission of some items from a form I have by doing the following:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['itemId']>0)
{
    if (array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['cart']['itemId']))
    { 
    }
    else 
    {
        $pid=$_REQUEST['itemId'];
        addtocart($pid,1);
        $itemAdded = 1;
        $max = 0; 
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) 
    { 
        $max = $max + $item['qty']; 
    }
    }
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
}
```

However, I keep getting "This webpage has a redirect loop". The thing is that I want my site to come back to the same website but not to get into the If anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would add to what Hast said that this approach is called PRG pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 0):

Use `unset($_POST);` or just redirect to another page after submitting. This is how it's done on most websites.

Comment: I put `unset($_POST['command']);` at the end (instead of `header()`) but did not help, when going to another page and pressing back or when reloading the page, it will keep on getting into the `IF`